# Django - challenge&response scenario (Create random string and sign by client so it check in server)

Tags: javascript, python, django

In asp.net I use this code:(server side)

```
if (!post-back)
   create challenge
else
   verify response
```

in java script:(client side)

```
onclientclick(aspBTN)
   response = sign(challenge)
```

note:
in top code page is load and create challenge so user by click on asp btn in html page run sign func in java script and in load page run verify response.

in Django I create challenge and save in hide item:
view.py file:

```
def index(request):   
    rng = uuid.uuid4().hex       
    request.session["challenge"] = rng   
    return render(request,"Djangoapp/index.html", {'challenge': rng})
```

and I define this btn:

```
<input id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="Sign()" />
```

in sign function I get response. Now I need to run server side function(python) to verify response.

I beginner in django.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, From what I understand, what you are trying to achieve on button click is a server side function call ?

There are various ways in which you could achieve that:
1. Xhr or Ajax Call
2. Using the fetch api in javascript

All these would interact with a RESTful API created on the django backend . For example :

```
def my_api_call(request):
    post_data = json.loads(request.body)
    perform_activity = post_data['activity_status']
    if perform_activity == True:
        call_function()

    return JsonResponse({"status":200, "response":"SUCCESS"})
```

If this is not what you are looking for, perhaps provide some more clarity by posting the code.

Comment: yes. I want to call server side function. please enplane more

Comment: could you share the code you're calling on button click and the exact server side function you're trying to call as well? I'd be able to explain it better with the exact code perhaps